# Is there a way to do a console.log from the firebase-messaging-sw with firebase cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to write a console.log statement for the firebase service worker that lives in the public folder of the react app I am working with. Is this possible?

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-messaging.js');

console.log("is service working working")

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "someapikey",
    authDomain: "somedomain",
    databaseURL: "somedburl",
    projectId: "someprojectid",
    storageBucket: "somestoragebucket",
    messagingSenderId: "someMessageId",
    appId: "someAppId" 
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from trying it to see if it works?  Or is there something you tried that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson so I have written the console.log but I am not seeing anything so I don't even know if its running

Comment: OK, you should edit the question to show the code that's not working the way you expect, and explain how you are running it. There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can copy it and duplicate the behavior.

Comment: @DougStevenson what I am really trying to do is come up with a simple way to see if my config vars are transferring to my firebase service worker file so that I can change my api keys, appId's etc between the staging and production environements

Answer (score 0):

My service worker was not running during this time, causing the service worker not to load. If anyone else has this problem make sure you load your firebase-massaging service worker file through importScripts with your current running service worker. In this example I assumed that firebase-messaging-sw.js would run but it did not and I had to import it through google workbox which runs the applications current service worker